# How to store array variable returned from another file?

Tags: php, arrays

I've a PHP Configuration File in TYPO3 like

```
<?php
return array(
    'DB' => array(
        'database' => 'vicous',
        'extTablesDefinitionScript' => 'extTables.php',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'password' => '',
        'socket' => '',
        'username' => 'root',
    )
);
?>
```

I want to get this array on an external php file. How to get that?

Something like this.

```
function getArray("filepath"){
   $variable = filepath return that array
}
```

My requirement is to get array inside $variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`include` and `require` behave exactly like you want:

```
$variable = include 'path/to/file.php';
```

From [the docs](https://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file
>   in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script
>   which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included
>   files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a
>   normal function.

Answer (score 1):

### You Could use like

```
function getArray($path){
   return $variable = require_once( $path );
}
```